# How to remove/delete first space of word using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to remove first space from text field. i have created function which allow only characters.
    Here is my html code :

```
<form:input path="deliveryBoyName" id="deliveryBoyName"
        maxlength="100" class="form-control" 
       onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);">
</form:input>
```

Here is my javascript function : 
    function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {

```
try {
    if (window.event) {
        var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
        var charCode = e.which;
    }
    else { return true; }
    if (charCode == 0 || charCode == 8 || charCode == 17 || charCode == 20 || charCode == 32 || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.Description);
} }
```

Now if user first types space then it should remove. starts only from character.

```
For example : 
If user types like " Hello World" 
Then it should not allowed. 
If user type like "Hello World" then its should allowed. please help me.    
Thank you in advance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to allow space only when it is not the first character.

This is what you want, i.e. your function removing all the unnecessary code:

```
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
  var charCode = e ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;

  return (charCode == 0  || charCode == 8  || charCode == 17 || charCode == 20 ||
          (t.value.length && charCode == 32) || 
          (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || 
          (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript `trim()` function can remove white spaces from both the side.

Here is working fiddle -

```js
var str = "   Did you find solution Ashish? If yes then tick it.";
alert(str.trim());
```

Comment: It will not work in my scenario. because i want to remove first space only. withing two words space should allowed. @kalpeshSIngh

Comment: It won't remove spaces in between two words. It will remove from start and end. :)